# My student visa (type D) expires 1-2 days before the final exam. I'm so confused

Tags: student-visa, schengen, overstay

I’m a non-EU citizen and studying in a Master’s Degree in Italy. I checked my student visa, it expires on 24 January 2024, but the date of the final exam in the university is either on 25 or 26 January 2024. So I told my university about this issue, and they said to me “stick around 22-23 but not guaranteed 100%”. I already contacted the embassy in Italy and they said that the easiest way is to tell my university to change or reschedule before 24…

The permesso or permit to stay expires the same day as the visa …

I want to know if, worst case scenario, I have to go back to my country (Thailand) with an overstay of a day or 2, and will I get banned in the future?

I’m confused about my issue so much because before I came here the document from the university mentioned that my course started on February 2023 and ended on 26 January 2024, but why did I get a visa until 24 January 2024?

What if I have a physical document that shows about the last date of the end of my master's degree and the reason why I overstayed 1-2 days when I had to go through passport control. Does that make sense?

I already booked my flights from Malpensa to Zurich for transit directly to Thailand. Unfortunately, they can't refund but still can change the date of the flight. (I don't want to cancel my flight because it's around 2,000 euros).

Comment: Under no circumstances should you simply overstay! There is no valid excuse that justifies overstaying, and you'll only be shooting your own foot. Either get an official visa extension somehow or get your university to reschedule the exam and then leave.

Comment: l don't get it even if when l applied student visa in my country with a document from the university that shows exactly the date of started and ended by 26, but l still got on 24. 
The worst thing that happened in my abroad life.

Comment: Not helpful now, but the best thing would probably been to have fixed the visa mistake when you got it.

Comment: What happens if the worst case, the university can't change the date of the final exam which means I'm overstaying a day for sure.. so if any chance of being denied boarding to Zurich even though l have a boarding pass to my country anyway? or they still let me go home but l have a chance to be rejected visa in the future? I'm stressed about this.

Comment: “I’m overstaying a day for sure” — Again: don’t. You can expect anything from jail time to damaging your future prospects of returning to the EU. What exactly will happen in your case is hard to say, but these are real possibilities. The best course of action is to politely petition the visa issuing authority to grant an extension/rectify their mistake; the second best is to petition the university to move the date; and the 3rd best is to come back at a later date on a new visa to take your exam. Does it suck? Yes. Can you simply do what you want? **NO!**

Comment: I've been trying to solve this issue since September but the first problem that the university said to me was that trying to stick but not guaranteed so l contacted the embassy and they said that the easiest way l have to argue with your university and l did but they still gave me like "remind us again in December when we starting schedule.. and also l went to the immigration in Italy and they said to me can't do anything even l have to renew a permit to stay that l have to wait around 4-5 months to collect a physical card.. this is the worst thing ever in my life.

Comment: l hope only the best way that the university understands my issue and changes the schedule before my visa expires.

Comment: You keep talking about Visa, but you should have a Residence Permit (visa is irelevant), why not just extend your Residence Permit?

Comment: l would say if l extend my Residence Permit l have to wait around 4-5 months to collect physical cards and l have to pay for a new long-contract apartment ( Minimum 6 months up )and the insurance again. Moreover, when l applied for a Residence permit l only got the receipt that only works in Italy but the problem is that l have to transit to Zurich so the receipt doesn't work there. Also, l prefer going back to my home country after finishing my master's degree as well.

Comment: "they said that the easiest way is to tell my university to change or reschedule before 24": it may be the easiest, but that does not mean that it's the only possibility.  If the university can't reschedule, does the "embassy in Italy" have a solution such as applying for an extension? Why are you talking to an embassy in Italy, anyway? You should be talking to the Italian government, which doesn't have any embassies in Italy. Are you asking the Thai embassy for advice? Okay, but don't rely on them. If you're planning to stay beyond the expiration of your permit, apply for an extension today.

Answer (score 0):

You can request a permesso provisorio from the Questura, which can allow you to stay legally in Italy for 1 to 3 months.